# Ajuda com lógica

Tags: java, xml, lista

Tenho um método que lê várias tags de um arquivo .xml e retorna uma lista preenchida pelos dados lidos.

Problema: Cada arquivo xml tem vários lotes e dentro do lote tem várias guias, por exemplo, tenho um Cliente chamado Rodrigo e ele está em uma guia com um procedimento X, o sistema consegue ler esse cliente, ao passar para a outra guia tenho o Cliente Rodrigo novamente, porem agora nessa guia ele tem vários procedimentos: y, z, w... Quando minha lista é retornada e eu gero o relatório ele sempre repete o nome do Cliente, dessa forma:

```
Nome: Rodrigo
Procedimento X

Nome Rodrigo
Procedimento Y

Nome Rodrigo
Procedimento Z

Nome Rodrigo
Procedimento W
```

Eu queria exibi-los de tal forma:

```
Nome Rodrigo
Procedimento X //Esse é p procedimento da primeira guia, como só tem um ele é separado

Nome Rodrigo //Na segunda guia o cliente Rodrigo possui 3 procedimentos, então todos são listados juntos
Procedimento Y
Procedimento Z
Procedimento W
```

Método:

```
public List<Procedimentos> realizaLeituraXML(String arquivoXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        //fazer o parse do arquivo e criar o documento XML
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(arquivoXML);

        Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList tagdadosLote = elem.getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosLote");

        List<Procedimentos> listaLote = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.printf("\n tagdadosLote %s ", tagdadosLote.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < tagdadosLote.getLength(); i++) {
            NumeroLote n = new NumeroLote();
            String lote = "";

            Element elementoLote = (Element) tagdadosLote.item(i);
            lote = pegaTag(elementoLote, "unimed:numeroLote");

            NodeList tagGuia = (NodeList) elementoLote.getElementsByTagName("unimed:guia");
            // Como sabemos pela estrutura que só tem 1 elemento não necessitamos de um for podendo fixar o indice.
            NodeList tagdadosGuia = ((Element) tagGuia.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosGuia");

            for (int y = 0; y < tagdadosGuia.getLength(); y++) {
                //Procedimentos proc = new Procedimentos();
                Procedimentos contato = new Procedimentos();
                NodeList tagBeneficiario0 = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:beneficiario");
                NodeList tagProcedimentos = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimentos");
                NodeList tagProcedimentos1 = ((Element) tagProcedimentos.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosProcedimento");

                Element elementoBeneficiarioname = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
                String nomeBeneficiario = (pegaTag(elementoBeneficiarioname, "unimed:nomeBeneficiario"));
                contato.setNomeBeneficiario(nomeBeneficiario);

                for (int a = 0; a < tagProcedimentos1.getLength(); a++) {
                    NodeList tagProcedimento = ((Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(a)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimento");

                    for (int b = 0; b < tagProcedimento.getLength(); b++) {
                        //Aqui é onde pego os demais dados Do arquivo XML e passo para meu objeto "contato"
                        //Deixei vazio pois é um metodo muito extenso

                        listaLote.add(contato);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        //System.err.println("Lista lote: " + listaLote);
        return listaLote;

    }
```

Como posso fazer para listar esses dados da forma que quero? Quando eu coloco `listaLote.add(contato);` no `For` que percorre `tagDadosGuia` Ele lista o nome dos Clientes certo, porém pega apenas o primeiro procedimento
dessa forma:

```
Nome Rodrigo
Procedimento X

Nome Rodrigo
Procedimento Y //Para nesse procedimento e não pega os restantes Z e W
```

Ele só pega todos os procedimentos se a `listaLote.add(contato);` ficar dentro do ultimo `For` mas quando isso acontece ele sempre repete os nomes como mostrado acima, Obrigado.

---

**Atualizada 25/05**

Minha classe Procedimentos:

```
public class Procedimentos {

    private String numLote;
    private String dataRealizacao;
    private String descriçãoServico;
    private String codTab;
    private String codigoServico;
    private String quantidadeExecutada;
    private BigDecimal valorProcessado;
    private BigDecimal valorLiberado;
    private BigDecimal valorGlosa;
    private String codigoGlosa;
    private String sequenciaGuiaProcedimento;
    private String sequenciaGuiaDados;
    private String nomeBeneficiario;
    private String valorLiberadoGuia;
    private String numeroGuiaSenha;

    private List<DetalhesProcedimentos> listaProcedimentos;
    ...
```

Dai no método que le o xml eu declarei:

```
 List<DetalhesProcedimentos> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

e dentro do `for` que percorre a `tagProcedimento` eu fiz isso:

```
DetalhesProcedimentos p1 = new DetalhesProcedimentos();
Element elementoBeneficiarioDescricaoServico = (Element) tagProcedimento.item(b);
                        beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiarioDescricaoServico, "unimed:descricao"));
                        p1.setDescricaoServico(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiarioDescricaoServico, "unimed:descricao"));

list.add(p1);
p.setListaProcedimentos(list);
```

E essa é a classe DetalhesProcedimentos:

```
public class DetalhesProcedimentos {

    private String dataRealizacao;
    private String descricaoServico;

    public String getDataRealizacao() {
        return dataRealizacao;
    }

    public void setDataRealizacao(String dataRealizacao) {
        this.dataRealizacao = dataRealizacao;
    }

    public String getDescricaoServico() {
        return descricaoServico;
    }

    public void setDescricaoServico(String descricaoServico) {
        this.descricaoServico = descricaoServico;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DetalhesProcedimentos{" + "dataRealizacao=" + dataRealizacao + ", descricaoServico=" + descricaoServico + '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual a estrutura desse arquivo XML?

Comment: Então o Arquivo é gigante, tem `32k` de linhas. Eu usei esse monte de for pois foi a única forma que consegui pegar os dados das tags que se repetem, como a tagDadosGuia que se repete e dentro dela a tag Procedimentos pode se repetir também. Vou tentar de montar um exemplo.

Comment: Aqui está um exemplo do arquivo, eu editei ele e diminui o seu tamanho, repare que a tagLote nem se fechou ainda pois só esse lote já é grande..

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!7hwgEJRS!cf3CjpsXPmlLjvwA9L1DxdBG-eD86RfOeahcXohhDtw

Comment: Só precisamos ver a estrutura.... não o arquivo em si... 
Pelo menos para mim com a estrutura fica mais simples de ter uma visão de como ajudar.

Comment: Esse arquivo que eu upei é a estrutura, é que mesmo assim fica um pouco grande pra postar. Não é o arquivo inteiro, apenas uma parte

Comment: Acho que o problema pode estar nesse trecho `Procedimentos contato = new Procedimentos();` ele fica dentro do ultimo `FOR` dessa forma ele sempre repete os nomes, e quando eu coloco ele no Primeiro `FOR` os nomes ficam certos, porem os procedimentos que são preenchidos no ultimo `FOR` ficam todos repetidos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi sua classe Procedimentos() irá conter um `contato` (vamos assumir que seja apenas o nome) e uma lista de `n` `procedimentos`

Então o pseudo código deve ser mais ou menos esse (Omiti partes do *parse* do XML:

```
for (int y = 0; y < tagdadosGuia.getLength(); y++) {
    Procedimentos contato = new Procedimentos();
    NodeList tagBeneficiario0 = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:beneficiario");
    NodeList tagProcedimentos = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimentos");
    NodeList tagProcedimentos1 = ((Element) tagProcedimentos.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosProcedimento");

    Element elementoBeneficiarioname = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
    String nomeBeneficiario = (pegaTag(elementoBeneficiarioname, "unimed:nomeBeneficiario"));
    contato.setNomeBeneficiario(nomeBeneficiario);

    for (int a = 0; a < tagProcedimentos1.getLength(); a++) {
        NodeList tagProcedimento = ((Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(a)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimento");

        for (int b = 0; b < tagProcedimento.getLength(); b++) {
            // Aqui você terá n procedimentos então       
            contato.addProcedimeto(magicaPraPegarProcedimento())     
            // O método magicaPraPegarProcedimento assume que vocêpega um procedimento do XML. E então armazena num array na classe Procedimentos()                         
        }

        listaLote.add(contato); // Add o contato a lista 
    }

}
```

---

Edição baseado no seu *update* e na nossa discussão nos comentários.

Você entendeu minha sugestão um pouco errado. 
No lugar de `private List<Procedimentos> listaProcedimentos;`

Você vai ter uma lista de Procedimento, que será uma nova Classe, pode ser uma classe simples que tenha somente uma string. Inclusive você pode ter só uma lista de string.

Ficando assim:

`private List<String> listaProcedimentos;`

O que importa mesmo é que você tenha uma lista em `Procedimentos`, onde cada elemento dessa lista descreve um único procedimento. Ficou mais claro agora?

Assim você pode adicionar no `for` mais interno nessa lista e no final Procedimentos() conterá uma lista, e então você terá o resultado desejado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24110/discussion-between-otavio-and-techies).

Comment: Outros comentários da discussão também foram [movidos para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24143/discussion-on-answer-by-otavio-ajuda-com-logica)